# Is it possible to use in IDEA -Dfoo.path=${env_var:FOO_ENV_KEY}?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, environment-variables, runtime

-Dfoo.path=${env_var:FOO_ENV_KEY}?

```
 ${env_var:FOO_ENV_KEY}
```

Looks like no, works only  -Dapp.log.path=BAR_ENV_VALUE.

If yes, how?

Comment: No, it's not possible. I'm not sure where this syntax comes from, but it's definitely not a standard Java feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define environment variables in the Edit Configuration Dialog of IntelliJ which eliminates the need for bash parameter substitutions.